# How do I stop my ReactJS Form <textarea> value & onChange functions from adding extra commas to my text?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm building a web app in Typescript (Although, for the purposes of this question, ReactJS is all you need to know) and I'm trying to make a `<textarea>` in a form that can include Markdown Links - [Link Title](https://exampleurl.com).

The whole paragraph is then to be saved to my database as an array of objects so that when displaying the information to the user, I can present the links however I want.

I feel like I'm super close to the solution! I have given the `<textarea>` an `onChange` function and the resulting `value` and it very nearly seems to work. If I just input text, it will print it as expected. The problem comes when I try to add a link. It immediately begins to add commas into the text in any place that the string has been split. Worse, I also then cannot type anything more or backspace - it just adds more commas.

My code looks like this:

```
<textarea
value={furtherReading.map((dataObj) =>
    dataObj && dataObj.type === 'text'
        ? dataObj.data
            : dataObj &&
                '[' + dataObj.linkTitle + '](' + dataObj.data + ')'
    )}
onChange={(e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    let linkRegex = RegExp(/([])|\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)/gm);
    let linksArray = value.match(linkRegex);
    let firstLinkIndex = value.search(linkRegex);
    let linkObjArray: {
        type: string;
        data: string;
        linkTitle: string;
    }[] = [];
    linksArray?.forEach((link) => {
        let linkTitle = link.split('](')[0].slice(1);
        let linkData = link.split('](')[1].slice(0, -1);
        linkObjArray.push({
            type: 'link',
            data: linkData,
            linkTitle: linkTitle,
        });
    });

    let textRegex = RegExp(/\[.*?\]\(.*?\)/gm);
    let textSplit = value.split(textRegex);
    let textObjArray: {
        type: string;
        data: string;
    }[] = [];
    console.dir(textSplit)
    textSplit.forEach((textChunk) => {
        textObjArray.push({ type: 'text', data: textChunk });
    });

    let mergedObjArray: {
        type: string;
        data: string;
        linkTitle?: string;
    }[] = [];

    if (firstLinkIndex === -1) {
        setFurtherReading(textObjArray);
    } else if (firstLinkIndex === 0) {
        linkObjArray.forEach((linkObj, i) => {
            mergedObjArray.push(linkObj);
            mergedObjArray.push(textObjArray[i]);
        });
        setFurtherReading(mergedObjArray);
    } else {
        textObjArray.forEach((textObj, i) => {
            mergedObjArray.push(textObj);
            mergedObjArray.push(linkObjArray[i]);
        });
        setFurtherReading(mergedObjArray);
    }
}}></textarea>
```

So yeah, I basically create an array of links, then an array of the other texts, figure out which goes first and then merge them together.

In the value, I map out that array.

I hope somebody can help me!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are setting the result of a `map()` call as `value` for a textarea; this will force-turn the array into a string, which inserts commas in between the elements. You'll want to append a `.join('')` there to put the string together without anything in between.

Comment: Solved it in 6 minutes! Man, I love this community. Thanks man :)